# How to get rights for audio files on ubuntu phone?

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-touch, files, phone

I am trying to copy audio files from Aquaris Ubuntu phone to my PC (Ubuntu 14.04), but it says I do not have the rights to do so.

Other files like photos and films are no problem, only the music files make trouble. does anyone have a helpfull idea how to solve this?

TX!
J

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference in the permissions for those files. How did you get them on the phone? Are you copying them in Nautilus over the MTP connection? What is the exact error?
You can check the file permissions and ownership in a terminal window using adb shell or phablet-shell from your PC over the USB connection, or using terminal-app on the phone
ls -l /home/phablet/Music

Comment: Tx Pat 4 answer! I got them by downloading via DOWNNOW. When I copy them to my W7-pc, there is no problem, only when I try to bring them on Ubuntu. Not even per stick from the W7 I could bring them in.

My knowledge about using the terminal is poor, sorry, this doenst help me.

Comment: I downloaded them by DOWN NOW. But I dont have the knowledge to use the terminal for this :(